# How to avoid blocking web requests on a Tomcat web server?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, servlets

I was doing some reading on server-push and they mention that "each Server Push connections ties up a thread"

I'm a bit lost as to how threads are created by the web server (per request?, per servlet? per server?) and if there is some sort of lifecyle.

An explanation of how an application on a browser is treated from a server view would be very handy.

Comment: "It depends". This question is quite broad. At the very least, tag it with Java/Servlet if appropriate.

Comment: Depends on web server check this http://serverfault.com/questions/266114/do-nginx-performe-better-on-linux-compared-to-apache for apache - nginx

Comment: any pointers as to where to start so I can make a more specific approach? I really don't want to start Freezing calls without knowing what I'm getting into

Comment: just using plain Tomcat for an app making AJAX calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you can deduce from that statement is that the web server it is discussing has a thread associated with each connection that is open, even if it's not actively transferring data. You can't tell anything else just from that. The server might create a new thread for each connection, it might re-use a pool of threads, it might have threads associated with specific internal structures. There's no way to know.

Comment: thanks, I didn't expected web servers to be different on this aspect, thought they all would be handling the relation between connections/threads the same way

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on the concrete web-server being used.

Some really block a thread for that. Other support async IO which does not block a thread (it registers a callback with the Windows/Linux kernel).

But all have in common that they need to maintain a long-running connection with the client.